# Maze solver gets stuck in a loop at a dead-end

Tags: java, maze

I'm working in a Maze solver algorithm and everything is working fine until it hits a dead-end and gets stuck in a loop, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tkvp.png). The problem seems to be that when it want to turn around there aint enough space for it so instead it makes another turn since it faces a wall in front and thus gets stuck in an endless loop.

Here are the two codes I'm working with but the first one is the most relevant one.

`SimpleWindow` is the main window where everything gets drawn etc, and the `maze` class is the file which generates the mazes and values for example `wallAtLeft`, `wallInFront`, `atExit` (these are all boolean)

```
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.window.SimpleWindow;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.maze.*;

public class MazeTurtle extends Turtle {
protected int Maze;

public MazeTurtle(SimpleWindow w, int x, int y) {
    super(w, x, y);
}

public void walk(Maze maze) {
    Maze m = new Maze(4);
    Turtle t = new Turtle(w, m.getXEntry(), m.getYEntry());
    int x1 = m.getXEntry();
    int y1 = m.getYEntry();
    int dir = t.getDirection();
    t.penDown();

    while ((m.atExit(x1, y1)) == false) {
        if (m.wallAtLeft(dir, x1, y1) == true) {
            t.forward(1);
            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
        }

        else if (m.wallAtLeft(dir, x1, y1) == false) {
            t.left(90);
            t.forward(1);
            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
        }

        if (m.wallInFront(dir, x1, y1) == true) {
            t.left(-90);
            t.forward(1);
            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
        }

        x1 = t.getX();
        y1 = t.getY();
        dir = t.getDirection();
        System.out.println("X: " + x1 + "Y: " + y1);
    }

}

}
```

Here is the program that draws everything:

```
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.window.SimpleWindow;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.maze.*;

public class MazeTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Maze m = new Maze(4);
    SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(600, 600, "MazeTest");
    MazeTurtle t = new MazeTurtle(w, m.getXEntry(), m.getYEntry());
    t.penDown();
    m.draw(w);
    t.walk(m);
}

}
```

The maze class with descriptions if it is needed. Note that only some of the methods are needed for this. http://pastebin.com/gxSeEc2U

This is the turtle class I'm using: http://pastebin.com/0RqbVudn

Comment: Don't use too small corridor ;-)

Comment: Well I can only use these predetermined labyrinths. There are a total of 5. It completes the first 3 without any problem but in the 4th and 5th it gets stuck in dead-ends.

Comment: Can you increase your System.out to include direction as well as the x and y coordinates? If you see the direction flipping back and forth you'll probably identify your infinite loop.

Comment: I've added the direction to my System.out and the result is that it keeps turning -90 degrees.

Comment: If the source code hasn't changed then for it to always turn -90 then "m.wallInFront(dir, x1, y1) == true" must always be true. x1 and y1 wouldn't change (because you're facing) a wall so "dir" must not be changing the way you think it is.  In other words, if dir == 0, then after t.left(-90) dir == -90, after t.left(-90) dir == -180, after t.left(-90) then dir == 90 and after t.left(-90) dir == 0. That's not happening, I take it.

Comment: Nope, it goes like this when it enters the dead-end: 180 -> 90 -> 0 -> -90, then the direction doesn't change for ~100 loops after that it goes nuts and displays a direction ranging from 1000-10000. But these last loops aren't of importance I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
if (m.wallInFront(dir, x1, y1) == true) {
        t.left(-90);
        SimpleWindow.delay(10);
```

I replaced it with this:

```
if (m.wallInFront(dir, x1, y1) && m.wallAtLeft(dir, x1, y1) == true) {
            t.left(-90);
            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
        }
```

Now instead of checking one thing at a time it checks if there is a CORNER not only a wall.

Thank you all for the help on the way :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not be calling `t.forward(1);` in section below, **as there may be a wall again after changing the direction.**

```
    if (m.wallInFront(dir, x1, y1) == true) {
        t.left(-90);
        //t.forward(1);
        SimpleWindow.delay(10);
    }
```

I am just assuming `forward(1)` tries to move one step and may be resulting into issue if there is no space(wall in front)

Comment: Well, you were right that I don't really need `t.forward`but the issue still remains cause it it collides with its own tail. (Similar to the game "Snake")

Comment: @Rob: I think you need to handle if it doesn't move backwards(two lefts because of wall). That I think you can do be setting a move counter and use as: if turned, then increase by 1, if moved then reset to 0. Once done then if move count is 2 then add one additional move step. If still there is a wall, then assume its a dead end, turn two times and start moving back.

Comment: Algorithm looks solid ("follow the left wall").  Implemented properly, when facing a dead end, the turtle will turn to the right twice and begin backtracking.

Comment: @bdares: Please refer the updated comment. I am just trying to cover the sceario when right turn is available.

Comment: @Rob: Or `check if the wall is on LEFT, if so then check if the wall is on right. If no, move, if yes, start moving back.`

Comment: I don't think I understand how I should move backwards.

Added my turtle class for clarification.

Comment: @Rob, If the wall is in front and then you make two left tuns e.g. `t.left(-90); t.left(-90);`, it will start moving back, NO?? If you can't then what is your option when you hit dead end?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to do but when it turns backwards (-90)(-90) the turtle hits his own "tail" and thus turning left (-90) once again and gets stuck in an endless loop.

Currently I don't know what my options are, that's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: @Rob: Would you mind sharing those methods too, including your endless loop code?

Comment: My endless loop code is my first code which imports two classes "Turtle" and "Maze" I've added them to the bottom of my question as a pastebin link.

Comment: @Rob: OK. I will take a look and get back to you in few minutes.

Comment: Note that I'm not supposed to change anything within those two files.

Comment: @Yogendra Singh: I seem to have fixed it! :D See my answer below.

Comment: @Rob: I just logged in back the get your code from you link. Good to know it worked!! Just seeing partial code, it becomes little difficult to find syntactical issues.