# Recursive maze solver problems java

Tags: java, recursion, solver, maze

I have now got it to stop repeating infinitely, but it just keeps trying the same wrong path over and over again. Does anyone know of a way to get it to try different paths?

Key for the numbers:
0 is open
1 is a wall
2 is part of the path
3 is the end of the maze

```
    public class Maze{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] maze = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};
    boolean[][] posCheck = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length];
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++){
        if(maze[row][col]==0){
          r = row;
          c = col;
        }
      }
    }
    maze[r][c] = 3;
    mazeSolver(1, 0, maze, posCheck);
  }

  public static boolean mazeSolver(int r, int c, int[][]maze, boolean[][] posCheck){
    posCheck[r][c] = true;
    maze[r][c] = 2;

    if(maze[r][c] == 3){
      print(maze);
      return true;
    }

    if((c+1 < maze.length) && maze[r][c+1]==0 && !posCheck[r][c+1] && (mazeSolver(r, c + 1, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((r-1 >= 0) && maze[r-1][c]==0 && !posCheck[r-1][c] && (mazeSolver(r - 1, c, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((c-1 >= 0) && maze[r][c-1]==0 && !posCheck[r][c-1] && (mazeSolver(r, c - 1, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((r+1 < maze.length) && maze[r+1][c]==0 && !posCheck[r+1][c] && (mazeSolver(r + 1, c, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    print(maze);
    return false;
  }

  public static void print(int[][] maze){
    for(int row = 0; row<maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col<maze[row].length; col++)
        System.out.print(maze[row][col]);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you go trough a node, mark it as a special value '5' so you know if it is visited, when iterating you will know if you have been there before. Be sure to mark always0 nodes that dont need aother walk , lets say the 'leafs'.

Comment: Is recursion a requirement for this?

Comment: If the maze allows you to go to a location you already passed in your path, without going back after finding a dead end, you must be able to detect that in your code.

Comment: First issue I've spotted: you set `maze[r][c] = 2;` then you test `if(maze[r][c] == 3)`.....

Comment: Another one: is it okay to test `(c+1 < maze.length)`? Variable `c` seems to apply to maze rows, not to the maze itself.

Comment: How do you know that your program 'keeps trying the same wrong path over and over again'? I'm afraid you're wrong about that and you just did not wait long enough and did not read dumped images carefully enough to be sure... Your maze is approx 1700 cells, the 'wrong path' may be say a hundred steps long, and you made your program to print the whole maze with every `return false` from the recursion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294848/maze-solver-gets-stuck-in-a-loop-at-a-dead-end

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have:
INITIAL STATE

```
SW00WW
00W0WW
W000WW
W0WWWW
00000E
```

w - wall 
0 - unwalked path
S - starting point
E - end point
(X - walked point)

Explanation:

What we do? We iterate 0's and mark them with X  when we reach a leaf. If you have  from one point other  0's going you dont mark it as X only if you are sure you dont need to return again.

```
www00W     (see 'P' as an '0') we must go from 'S' to 'E' when we reach 'P' we have 2 moves from that point 
S00Pww      when iterating. As conclusion you let it be stil '0', and when we meet a first node 
www00E      that wont need another visit mark it as X.
```

Example:

```
SW00WW
x0W0WW
W000WW
W0WWWW
00000E

SW00WW
xxW0WW
W000WW
W0WWWW
00000E

SW00WW
xxW0WW
W000WW
W0WWWW
00000E

SW00WW
x0W0WW
W000WW
W0WWWW
00000E

SW00WW
xxW0WW
W0x0WW
W0WWWW
00000E

SW00WW
xxW0WW
W0xxWW
W0WWWW
00000E

SWxxWW   (made 3 steps on a first ipotetical choise)
xxWxWW
W0xxWW
W0WWWW
00000E

    SWxxWW   (made 4 steps on last row to the end)
    xxWxWW
    WxxxWW
    WxWWWW
    0xxxxE
```

Hope it helps, sorry for long example but I tried to make it clear.

PS: alternative  Depth first  search

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function will be much more 'readable' if you put all position validity tests in one place:

```
public static boolean mazeSolver(int r, int c, int[][]maze){
  if( ! isPositionValid(r, c, maze))
    return false;       // tried to flow outside the maze

  if(maze[r][c] == 3){  // is it a destination point?
    print(maze);        // solved
    return true;
  }

  if( maze[r][c] != 0)  // a wall, a path or already checked?
    return false;

  maze[r][c] = 2;       // mark position as a part of the path

  if( mazeSolver(r, c + 1, maze)))  // try to extend the path and
    return true;                    // return if solution found
  if( mazeSolver(r, c - 1, maze)))
    return true;
  if( mazeSolver(r + 1, c, maze)))
    return true;
  if( mazeSolver(r - 1, c, maze)))
    return true;

  maze[r][c] = 4;     // dead-end - mark the position 'checked'
  return false;
}


public static boolean isPositionValid(int r, int c, int[][]maze){
  return r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < maze.size && c < maze[r].size;
}
```